# Connecting DMS to S3

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, aws-dms

We are trying to get DMS set up with an S3 Source however we are unable to connect the replication instance to the Source S3 endpoint.

When we run a connection test on the source endpoint, the error we receive is:

`Error Details: [errType=ERROR_RESPONSE, status=1020414, errMessage= Failed to connect to database., errDetails=]`

We have followed [the documentation](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/dms/latest/userguide/CHAP_Source.S3.html) however we are still unable to get the connection to work. The bucket is within the VPC that the replication instance has access to, and the IAM role has the `GetObject`, `ListBucket` and `dms*` permissions. I'm 95% sure that the JSON mapping file is set up correctly with schema and table names pointing to the right place.

Due to the lack of error messages or detailed reasons why we can't connect to the source database (the S3 bucket/CSV file), debugging this feels a tad hit and miss. We are using the Amazon Console and not the CLI, if that makes much of a difference.

Comment: Did you figure this out in the end? If you're using DMS as an IAM user, then this page could help: https://docs.aws.amazon.com/dms/latest/userguide/CHAP_Security.IAMPermissions.html

Comment: Did you figure this out? I am having the same issue there as well

Comment: I'm hitting the same problem -- any chance you found a solution?

Comment: Could you provide the detailed JSON of the role attached to you DMS instance? Then, do you have further information about you VPC/subnets configuration? Is there any S3 gateway configured etc. ? Last thing, did you check region issues like mentioned here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59516519/dms-s3-source-endpoint-connection-fails?rq=1 ?

Answer (score 1):

I had this same error.

Check this [troubleshooting guide](https://aws.amazon.com/pt/premiumsupport/knowledge-center/dms-connection-test-fail-s3/). It covers the basic configuration problems you might run into.

My answer wasn't there, tho, and I couldn't find it anywhere, not even asking in the official forums.

In my case, for some reason I thought I should use the full bucket name in the "Bucket Name" field, like "arn:aws:s3:::my-bucket". Probably because I had to use the ARN for the role in the previous field.

And the error message when you try to connect to it will not be clear, it only says it couldn't connect to the bucket. Anyway, **you don't need to provide an ARN, just the bucket's name, as in "my-bucket".**