# dms s3 source endpoint connection fails

Tags: amazon-s3, aws-dms

Getting below connection error when trying to validate S3 source endpoint of DMS.

```
Test Endpoint failed: Application-Status: 1020912, Application-Message: Failed to connect to database.
```

Followed all the steps listed in the below links but still maybe I am missing something...

https://aws.amazon.com/premiumsupport/knowledge-center/dms-connection-test-fail-s3/
https://docs.aws.amazon.com/dms/latest/userguide/CHAP_Source.S3.html

The role associated with the endpoint does have access to the S3 bucket of the endpoint, along with dms being listed as trusted entity.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I got this same error when trying to use S3 as a target.

The one thing not mentioned in the documentation, and which turned out to be the root cause for my error, is that the DMS Replication Instance and the Bucket need to be in the **same region**.

Comment: That was it for me!

Answer (score 1):

I was facing similar issue & replication instance engine was 3.4.7...
I created vpc gateway to s3 (goto vpc console-> create endpoint-> select same vpc id as replication instance-->search S3 marked as gateway & select it--> create endpoint )
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3TFMG.png)

The official documentation is here: [VPC - DMS endpoints](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/dms/latest/userguide/CHAP_VPC_Endpoints.html)